# Howto access file system-dependant data from a lkm

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm developing a LKM for Linux kernel, and I want it to get some specific information that is file system related. In fact this information is the field [i_crtime](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L655) (creation time) of a inode structure of a ext4 file system.

My question is, How could I access this field from a lkm? Right now I know how to get the inode of a specific file:

```
kern_path(<path to file>, LOOKUP_FOLLOW, &path)
```

So after this I have the inode via:

```
path.dentry->d_inode
```

But this inode (d_inode) is the generic VFS [inode](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2/include/linux/fs.h#L749) structure, not the ext4_inode previously shown (nor ext4_inode_info neither).

Anybody knows how to do that? I'm trying to study the VFS code, the stat (coreutil) code, stracing it and I'm still stucked :-S

TIA.

Answer (score 2):

The EXT4_I() [function](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2/fs/ext4/ext4.h#L1258) gets you *ext4_inode_info* from the VFS inode. But the VFS inode's ctime is exactly the [same](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.2/fs/ext4/ialloc.c#L869) as that of the EXT4 inode. So you might as well access *inode->i_ctime*.

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Btw, you have linked the ext4_new_inode() function, at that point all of the timestamps are the same for a logical reason, but they change through time (all but crtime in fact... i guess).

Comment: Mmmm, I have been trying to use it but I have realize that EXT4_I() is a helper function for ext4 driver, is not exported so we cannot use it out of the ext4 driver scope. I have even tried to use container_of() instead o EXT4_I() but I have no definition of struct ext4_inode_info. Do you know what to do now?

Comment: "#include <linux/../../fs/ext4/ext4.h>" in your LKM

Comment: The VFS inode is a structure embedded inside the filesystem specific inode(ext4_inode_info in this case). All timestamp updates are made to the VFS inode which is then synced to disk later on.See ext4_rename() for example.AFAIK,your VFS inode timestamps should reflect the latest c/a/mtime values at all times.